# Delete all old files, but keep newest 4 files using ansible-playbook

Tags: linux, shell, ansible

I would like to delete all old files, and keep newest 4 files. The output isn't what i expected. Even i use absent on file modules, but it doesn't delete the files.

My files are here

```
# ls -l /home/tomcat/backup
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 as
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 asd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 df
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 fas
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 y6
```

ansible.yml

```
- name: Prerequsite Deployement | Get first 4 files
  shell: "ls -t {{ item.path }}/{{ item.filename }} | tail -n +4"
  with_items:
    - { path: /home/tomcat/backup, filename: "*" }
  register: files_matched
  tags: prerequsite_deployment

- debug:
    msg: "{{item.stdout_lines}}"
  with_items: "{{files_matched.results}}"
  tags: prerequsite_deployment

- name: Prerequsite Deployement | Clean up path
  file:
    path: "{{item.stdout_lines}}"
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{files_matched.results}}"
  tags: prerequsite_deployment
```

the result ouput

```
# ls -l /home/tomcat/backup
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 as
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 asd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 df
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 fas
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 y6
```

My expected result output

```
# ls -l /home/tomcat/backup
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  3 14:21 4
```

Comment: You can use the find module and specify age. This will give you the list (register) of all the files older than the age selected (you can use the values for the 4th file). Then just do state: absent for all the files in the register.

Comment: Yes, but sometime more multiple files created on one day, that why I didn't use `find` module. Then I use shell instead.

Comment: Ah I see. You can try using a simple loop then. Loop 4 times and put those in register. Not a very clean solution though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute *`mtime`* of the dictionaries, listed in the registered variable *`result.files`*, can be used to [*sort*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.sort) the files. For example

```yaml
  - find:
      paths: dir1
      recurse: true
    register: result

  - set_fact:
      my_files: "{{ result.files|
                    sort(attribute='mtime')|
                    map(attribute='path')|
                    list }}"
```

Optionally, list the files but the last (newest) 4 files

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: my_files[0:-4]
```

and delete the files if this is what you want

```yaml
  - file:
      state: absent
      path: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ my_files[0:-4] }}"
```