# Delete all old files, but keep newest 3 files for same file name and different path

Tags: ansible

Hi can i know how can i keep the latest 3 files based on file name and path. For instance i have

- fileAbackup1.war, fileAbackup2.war, fileAbackup3.war, fileAbackup4.war
- fileBbackup1.war, fileBbackup2.war, fileBbackup3.war, fileBbackup4.war

So i should keep

- fileAbackup1.war, fileAbackup2.war, fileAbackup3.war
- fileBbackup1.war, fileBbackup2.war, fileBbackup3.war

I know the part of finding files and deleting files older than x days. I already done the coding part. But i need have some filter to keep 3 backup files of same name of different path

Updated

Below is my ansible code

```
- name: Find files
  find:
    paths: "{{ remove_file_path }}"
    use_regex: yes
    patterns:
      - '*.war.*.backup*'
      - '{{ rar_file_name }}.rar.*.bakup*'
      - '.*\..*\.\d+\.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}@\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~$'
    age: 5d
    recurse: yes
  register: removeFile
  
- name: Delete files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ removeFile.files }}"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and pick a more appropriate tag, as your question has nothing to do with ansible

Comment: hi i want to do this in ansible playbook. i will share my coding shortly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all old files, but keep newest 4 files using ansible-playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503204/delete-all-old-files-but-keep-newest-4-files-using-ansible-playbook)

Comment: hi for different file name in different path it will also keep 4 backup  latest backup for each file regardless of path?

Answer (score 2):

The tasks below

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: dir1
        patterns: '*.war'
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        my_files: "{{ result.files|
                      map(attribute='path')|
                      sort|
                      list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_files[0:3]
```

give

```yaml
  my_files[0:3]:
    - dir1/fileAbackup1.war
    - dir1/fileAbackup2.war
    - dir1/fileAbackup3.war
```

If you need the filenames only map the filter `basename`. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_files: "{{ result.files|
                      map(attribute='path')|
                      map('basename')|
                      sort|
                      list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_files[0:3]
```

give

```yaml
  my_files[0:3]:
    - fileAbackup1.war
    - fileAbackup2.war
    - fileAbackup3.war
```

---

> Q: *"Will it have file fileBbackup1.war, fileBbackup2.war, and fileBbackup3.war as well?"*

A: Yes. It will. Create a dictionary of the lists. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_files: "{{ my_files|default({})|
                      combine({item: result.files|
                                     map(attribute='path')|
                                     map('basename')|
                                     select('search', item)|
                                     sort|
                                     list}) }}"
      loop:
        - fileAbackup
        - fileBbackup

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value[0:3] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_files|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

give

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=fileAbackup) => 
  msg:
  - fileAbackup1.war
  - fileAbackup2.war
  - fileAbackup3.war
ok: [localhost] => (item=fileBbackup) => 
  msg:
  - fileBbackup1.war
  - fileBbackup2.war
  - fileBbackup3.war
```

Comment: hi will it have file fileBbackup1.war, fileBbackup2.war, and fileBbackup3.war as well?

Comment: can i know map(attribute='path') -> display path/file name,                                    map('basename') -> display only the file name, what is this purpsoe -> select('search', item)

Comment: Remove the line with the `select` filter. You'll see it.

Comment: yea i am trying it out.

Comment: hi how do we pass value from find file register to set_Fact as i saw u have written a loop

Comment: if you able to help me me let me know ya

Comment: loop:
    - "{{ file.FileName }}"
    - "{{ content.VeriableName }}". i added this but got error list object' has no attribute 'FileName".what can be done ya

Comment: @VladimirBotka, saw yours answer. Would you mind to share how it can be done in delete file module in Ansible. How can i pass it to delete module. I have similar but different issue.  Mine involving dictionary and file module in ansible

Answer (score 1):

This command will provide the information you need.

`ls -1 *.war | sort -r | head -n -3`

Explanation
`ls -1 *.war | sort -r`  Performs a reverse sort and displays just the filenames
`head -n -3`       Displays all except the first 3

You can pipe this to the command that deletes the files or you can run the following
`rm $(ls -1 | sort -r | head -n -3)`

Comment: how can it bee done via ansible plyabook?  i will update with my coding shortly